# How do I add a "pet" particle to minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to recreate the flame fairy from Mineplex, but I need a little help. I tried attaching a command block with: `/execute @p[m=1] ~-1 ~ ~ particle flame ~ ~ ~ 10 100 10 0.5 1` to a redstone clock, but I couldn't see the particles. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to add the player who active the flame fairy a scoreboard such as
/scoreboard objectives add flamefairy dummy
/scoreboard players set @p flamefairy 1
/execute @a[score_flamefairy_min=1] ~ ~ ~ particle flame ~ ~ ~ 0 0 0 0 10 10 0.5 1

Comment: So my username in minecraft is XtremeCrafter. how would that change each command?

Comment: Never mind. It worked. I never realized it was for everybody who had the scoreboard set. Thank you. Also, is there a way to alter the execute command so that it would be to the left of me, no matter what x y z is?

Comment: @HenryDillman No, unfortunately, there isn't a way to summon particles to your relative left side. Simply because the ~x ~y ~z offsets are still aligned to the world-axis.